# How does the electromagnetic dipole operator appear in the decay $b \rightarrow s \gamma$?

Tags: electromagnetism, quantum-field-theory, operators, dipole, effective-field-theory

I was analyzing the effective theory of the process $b \rightarrow s \gamma$ and and I was in doubt about the emergence of the effective operator of photon dipole

$$O_7 = e m_b \bar{s}_L \sigma_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu} b_R.$$

I saw that it emerge of the electroweak penguin diagram in that we have a top quark in the loop and a photon in the vertex. My attempt was integrate out the $W$ boson and the top quark, but I didn't get this operator.

Can anyone help me?

Appreciate.

Comment: That operator is generated at loop level, so getting it from integrating out $t$ and $W$ will be hard. The easiest way is probably to compute it by matching it with the SM loop in the limit $E \ll m_W, m_t$.

Comment: [⚫](https://doi.org/10.1146/annurev.nucl.48.1.253).

Comment: I tried that and I couldn't do it either. Maybe there's some kind of algebraic manipulation I'm missing.